# Cancelling event invoking sequence in previous invoked method

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a derived class from Button control class. When I use the control, I need to make to be prevented from invocation in some situation. The situation is already defined in the derived class, myClick function. I guessed there is a way like setting e.Cancel = true, but I can't. Can you give a simple suggestion to solve this task?

```
public class SButton : Button
{
    public SButton() : base()
    {
        Click += new System.EventHandler(myClick);
    }


    private void myClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if( meHandsome )
        {
            // here I want to prevent no more event invocation!
        }
    }
}



public partial class UTeachAdvanced : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl
{
    private void UTeachAdvanced_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SButton btn = new SButton();
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.Write("ugly");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The situation is already defined in the derived class.

The `Click` event raises by [`Control.OnClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) method. To prevent raising `Click` event, you can override `OnClick` and call `base.OnClick` only if the criteria to prevent the click is not true:

```
public class SampleButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!criteriaToPrevent)
            base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of subscribing _Click Event_, i overrided _onClick_ function. it works!

Comment: Yes, this is the way you should go :)